# Is a ghusl necessary in this situation

Tags: ghusl

Salam, if one had dirty thoughts during the day and had an erecttion that subsided, then an hour or 2 later sperm exited, is a ghusl necessary?

Comment: Are you sure that semen exited? Or was it just madhiy?

Comment: I’m certain it was semen

Answer (score 1):

Assalmualaykum,

Any ejaculation of sperm, regardless of the cause will result in needing ghusl. In this case, you will need ghusl and will not be able to:

- Pray or touch the quran
- Pray salaah
- perform the Tawaaf of the ka'bah
- perform Sajdah'e'Tilaawat

until ghusl is completed.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Jazakallah for the answer.